# ERROR: org.apache.hadoop.fs.UnsupportedFileSystemException: No FileSystem for scheme "maprfs"

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, apache-storm, mapr

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rxBLb.png)

While writing the output to FS, getting the above error. Using the storm client.  getting the below error ERROR: org.apache.hadoop.fs.UnsupportedFileSystemException: No FileSystem for scheme "maprfs".

Here is the log.

```
consumer=org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer@305c2b21, topic-partitions=[]]
2024-03-28 10:57:12.259 o.a.s.k.s.KafkaSpout Thread-15-kafka-spout-executor[3, 3] [INFO] Partitions reassignment. [task-ID=3, consumer-group=topic03-group-id, consumer=org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer@305c2b21, topic-partitions=[topic03-0]]
2024-03-28 10:57:12.264 o.a.k.c.c.i.AbstractCoordinator Thread-15-kafka-spout-executor[3, 3] [INFO] [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=topic03-group-id] Discovered group coordinator node6.ezm.tst:9092 (id: 2147483647 rack: null)
2024-03-28 10:57:12.271 o.a.k.c.c.i.Fetcher Thread-15-kafka-spout-executor[3, 3] [INFO] [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=topic03-group-id] Resetting offset for partition topic03-0 to offset 0.
2024-03-28 10:57:12.277 o.a.s.k.s.KafkaSpout Thread-15-kafka-spout-executor[3, 3] [INFO] Initialization complete
2024-03-28 10:57:12.278 o.a.s.k.s.KafkaSpout Thread-15-kafka-spout-executor[3, 3] [INFO] Partitions assignments has changed, updating metrics.
2024-03-28 10:57:12.278 o.a.s.k.s.m.KafkaOffsetMetricManager Thread-15-kafka-spout-executor[3, 3] [INFO] Registering metric for topicPartition: topic03-0
2024-03-28 10:57:12.279 o.a.s.k.s.m.KafkaOffsetTopicMetrics Thread-15-kafka-spout-executor[3, 3] [INFO] Create KafkaOffsetTopicMetrics for topic: topic03
2024-03-28 10:57:12.281 o.a.s.k.s.m.KafkaOffsetPartitionMetrics Thread-15-kafka-spout-executor[3, 3] [INFO] Running KafkaOffsetMetricSet
2024-03-28 10:57:12.285 o.a.s.u.Utils Thread-15-kafka-spout-executor[3, 3] [ERROR] Async loop died!
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecords org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.Consumer.poll(java.time.Duration)'
    at org.apache.storm.kafka.spout.KafkaSpout.pollKafkaBroker(KafkaSpout.java:360) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
    at org.apache.storm.kafka.spout.KafkaSpout.nextTuple(KafkaSpout.java:289) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
    at org.apache.storm.executor.spout.SpoutExecutor$2.call(SpoutExecutor.java:187) ~[storm-client-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.apache.storm.executor.spout.SpoutExecutor$2.call(SpoutExecutor.java:153) ~[storm-client-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.apache.storm.utils.Utils$1.run(Utils.java:398) [storm-client-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) [?:?]
2024-03-28 10:57:12.275 o.a.s.u.Utils Thread-16-hdfs-bolt-executor[2, 2] [ERROR] Async loop died!
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error preparing HdfsBolt: No FileSystem for scheme "maprfs"
    at org.apache.storm.hdfs.bolt.AbstractHdfsBolt.prepare(AbstractHdfsBolt.java:120) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
    at org.apache.storm.executor.bolt.BoltExecutor.init(BoltExecutor.java:128) ~[storm-client-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.apache.storm.executor.bolt.BoltExecutor.call(BoltExecutor.java:138) ~[storm-client-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.apache.storm.executor.bolt.BoltExecutor.call(BoltExecutor.java:54) ~[storm-client-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.apache.storm.utils.Utils$1.run(Utils.java:393) [storm-client-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) [?:?]
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.fs.UnsupportedFileSystemException: No FileSystem for scheme "maprfs"
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getFileSystemClass(FileSystem.java:3585) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:3608) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$300(FileSystem.java:174) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:3712) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:3663) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:557) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
    at org.apache.storm.hdfs.bolt.HdfsBolt.doPrepare(HdfsBolt.java:99) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
    at org.apache.storm.hdfs.bolt.AbstractHdfsBolt.prepare(AbstractHdfsBolt.java:118) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
    ... 5 more
2024-03-28 10:57:12.285 o.a.s.e.e.ReportError Thread-15-kafka-spout-executor[3, 3] [ERROR] Error
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecords org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.Consumer.poll(java.time.Duration)'
    at org.apache.storm.utils.Utils$1.run(Utils.java:413) ~[storm-client-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) [?:?]
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecords org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.Consumer.poll(java.time.Duration)'
    at org.apache.storm.kafka.spout.KafkaSpout.pollKafkaBroker(KafkaSpout.java:360) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
    at org.apache.storm.kafka.spout.KafkaSpout.nextTuple(KafkaSpout.java:289) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
    at org.apache.storm.executor.spout.SpoutExecutor$2.call(SpoutExecutor.java:187) ~[storm-client-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.apache.storm.executor.spout.SpoutExecutor$2.call(SpoutExecutor.java:153) ~[storm-client-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.apache.storm.utils.Utils$1.run(Utils.java:398) ~[storm-client-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    ... 1 more
```

Comment: 1) There's also an error from KafkaSpout that'll need fixed 2) Please show your core-site.xml to see your filesystem definitions

Comment: Could you also provide just a hint about your environment? It's really hard to even suggest where the problem might be without that kind of information.